# react native webview cache not working with IOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, caching, react-native-webview

react native web view cache not working with ios

i am using [react-native-web-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) but i have problem with cache is not working in IOS but in android is working good is anyone have idea about this problem ?